# where to use @ and $ for dynamic elements/variable in Python/RobotFramework. Example @{cookies} and ${cookies}

Tags: python, robotframework

I don't have any problem but trying to understand where to use @{any_variable} and ${any_variable}
"@" and "$" difference

```
:FOR    ${partner}    IN    @{partners_name}
      Set test variable   ${partner}
```

I don't have any error just want to understand where to use @ and $ 
or the difference between @ and $

Answer (score 5):

The `$` prefix stands for "use the value of that variable"; `@` is "expand the content of the container *(usually a list, but that's not the only option)*, and use that set of values".

For instance:

```
${a list}=    Create List    a    b    c
```

When used

```
FOR    ${value}    IN    @{a list}
```

, is evaluated by RF as

```
FOR    ${value}    IN    a     b    c
```

, which is the correct for-loop syntax.

---

But in the same time:

```
FOR    ${value}    IN    ${a list}
```

, is evaluated by RF as

```
FOR    ${value}    IN    ['a', 'b', 'c']   # this is a string, not an actual python list
```

, which is syntactically incorrect for RF.

---

In general, when you want to pass "the list members, each one separately" - use the `@`. When you need to pass the list variable itself - use the `$`.

This is a simplification, but covers the major use case.